# Volume icon in title bar while playing video - Noisy Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, titlebar

I don't know how to explain this, but here it goes..

Few days back I saw [image: See this picture] on Timesofindia's site.

The volume icon in the title bar only shows when the video in that page is running and once the video stops the icon disappears.

Isn't it a awesome thing?

I don't know whether it is a new functionality in the web industry or not, but I need the same functionality in my site also.
Also, I searched in Google for the same, but I couldn't find this.

NOTE: Even gmail has the same function for new chats

Comment: Hello Anusha.
It's seems that this is a new feature in the newest version of google chrome.
Check this article: http://chrome.blogspot.dk/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a browser feature](http://chrome.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html), not a site feature. You don't need to do anything.